# How To Delay NavigationView Icons Visibility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, fadein, android-navigationview

I saw an app, whose icon behavior in the `navigationView` delay it's visibility (Fade In- animation), yet my API for phone is 19.

My question is, **how can I access to these icons to delay its visibility? Is it possible to implement it without using third party library?**

Answer (score 1):

For your view in Java you can do something like this -

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
View.startAnimation(animation);
```

If you want to use only one if you wish to.
You can even stop it by calling clearing it

```
View.clearAnimation();
```

**OR other way**

For XML, in your `res/anim` folder make a file, suppose name is `fadein.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.1"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="2000"
      />
</set>
```

And in java

Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationU

```
tils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
View.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
```

Use `startAnimation()` in a method where navigation becomes visible

Comment: I will test this first, thank you for your time. What is tils by the way and is `View` refer to my navigationView. I have no background in animation, it's my first time.

Comment: `View` = your `ImageView` where icons are placed or it can be even your `TextView` but definitely I won't do that on `NavigationView` else that effect will be on `NavigationView` instead of at required place.